# How to create Custom Theme in Wordpress 5.5.3

Tags: theme-development

I want to create custom theme in word-press from scratch so can you have the idea about custom theme folder structure and development steps so please help me.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are countless guides online, just search 'Wordpress Theme creation' on Google.

A good place to start would be https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/guide-to-developing-a-wp-theme/

For folder structure I suggest you use a 'Wordpress Theme Boilerplate', you can generate one here: https://underscores.me/, but there are loads of other options. More are listed here:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/21-best-wordpress-starter-themes-for-developers/

Or if you don't know php, you could try this:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-easily-create-a-custom-wordpress-theme/

Entering the question you have asked here on Google will give you many more results which might fit your needs even better.